# Can the Artificer Artillerist's tiny-sized Eldritch Cannon that is not held in hand still ride or be carried elsewhere on the body?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, artificer

As an Artillerist Artificer, if I create a tiny-sized Eldritch Cannon with legs, can I place this cannon somewhere on my person and let it use its legs to hold on to my character (on my head, shoulder (Predator!), wrist, belt, top of my backpack, etc.)?

I understand that with RAW, it cannot move on its own into an occupied space, so it would not be able to climb up onto me, but I think that I should still be able to pick it up and place it somewhere as an object interaction.  It could use its legs to hold on once in place.  If I can control it from up to 60 feet away, I would think that it shouldn't hinder the use of my hands for other actions once it is there.

Comment: Are you basically asking if the tiny cannon can **mount** a medium character?

Answer (score 8):

## Yes, a Tiny-sized Eldritch Cannon (with or without legs) can be worn or carried on the body elsewhere than in the hand.

The key to understanding this issue is to recognize that an Eldritch Cannon is explicitly an object, more specifically

> a magical object

rather than a creature.

### As an object, the Eldritch Cannon doesn't work like a creature.

The rules on creature movement and creatures occupying spaces don't apply to objects. The rules don't expect players to engage in complex inventory-management or to supply sophisticated reasoning for carrying or navigating objects in the ordinary course. Objects, even sizable ones, can be borne about the body in any number of ways. A hat or helm might be worn atop the head, or secured by a chin-strap to dangle behind the head, or affixed to a belt, etc. A backpack or shield might be larger than one's torso, and yet they can be slung over the shoulder by a strap, or carried by a hand holding that same strap. A shield can even be strapped *to* a backpack. When a creature goes to pick up a backpack, we don't ask whether it's problematic that the creature is moving into the backpack's space. When the creature is carrying the backpack, we don't suppose that the backpack wouldn't naturally remain with the creature when the creature moves.

As an object, a Tiny cannon does not occupy its space. The requirement that an artillerist must

> create a Small or Tiny eldritch cannon in an unoccupied space

does not mean that all such cannons always occupy their spaces. The rules specify that

> a Small eldritch cannon occupies its space . . . .

Absent that specification, a Small cannon *would not* occupy its space. So we know that if the designers wanted a Tiny cannon to occupy its space, they would have said so.

### The liberal wording of the Eldritch Cannon ability offers an artificer latitude in shaping the cannon for convenience and portability.

The Eldritch Cannon ability says

> When you create the cannon, you determine its appearance and whether it has legs.

That statement gives an artillerist maximally broad power to give a cannon almost any form imaginable. The *only* limits are the ones set out in the ability regarding size and legs-or-no-legs. An artillerist could create a cannon in the form of a hat, or a brooch, or a ham sandwich. If the chosen form is one that common sense suggests can be borne about the body, then the cannon can be borne about the body. The ability's statement that

> a Tiny [cannon] *can* be held in one hand

(emphasis added) does not mean the cannon *must* be held in the hand. A cannon in the form of a hat could be worn on the head. A cannon in the form of a brooch could be pinned to clothing. Silly or not, it is a rules-accurate proposition that a cannon in the form of a sandwich could be clamped between the teeth. Heck, a cannon could be given a form that includes integrated straps, buckles, etc., for the very purpose of wearing it.

Finally, it is correct that a cannon with legs cannot move itself into an occupied space -- but only because the ability description says so. If the ability did not say so, there would be nothing to preclude a cannon from moving into an occupied space. By the same token, nothing prevents the artillerist from picking up a Tiny cannon and placing it on her body. Again, if the cannon were any other Tiny object, such as a glove, a key, or a lantern, we wouldn't think twice about letting a creature pick it up and wear or carry it around, moving from place to place with it. So there's no basis to say no when the Tiny object is an artillerist's cannon.

Answer (score 5):

### Probably not because making it work gets a bit messy

As you point out, the rule for Movement and Position (Moving Around Other Creatures) states:

> Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can't willingly end your move in its space.

However, the Eldritch Cannon is not a creature, despite the fact that it is kind of talked about in that way:

> The cannon is a magical object.

It's a little confusing because it seems to function in the same way a familiar or animal companion might but the normal rule for creatures sharing a space doesn't quite apply because of its status as an object.

So, from a rules standpoint, it could occupy the same space as you and you could use your reaction to get it to move with you. Narratively, you could say that it is perching on your shoulder as you do the moving.

However, the issues you will run into with this are:

- There's likely a big difference between your character's movement and that of the cannon. You'd have to limit your movement to the cannon's 15 movement.
- The cannon isn't a creature, so it can't mount, but that is effectively what you're trying to simulate and so you'd probably have to evaluate the rules interaction in this context. Plus, if you treat it as "walking with you" by the rules but "on your shoulder" for the story, what happens when you get fireballed? Do you treat the cannon as worn/carried?

I really like the idea of a ride-along cannon and I personally really want to work out a solution with you, so it's a good idea to talk with your DM about your intent and see if you can work out a (homebrew) solution.

Comment: I think my DM is more concerned about this bypassing the Cannon's own limited movement by allowing it to move with me. He feels that I should require one of my hands be unavailable if it rides me as an added cost.

Comment: @Kel That's a good point. I suppose you could say your character has only 15' of movement (maybe a bum leg) and compromise that way lol!

Comment: OP asks "can I place this cannon somewhere on my person and let it use its legs to hold on to my character", and to this part you suggest the answer is yes; can you support the idea that it could use its legs to hold on? (Or more clearly address this aspect of the question?)

Comment: To clarify a little, when I asked this, I was envisioning a cannon form that has more than 2 legs like a crustacean, insect, or arachnid shape.  I realize that the form you choose can make a big difference on how realistic it is for it to hold on.  It would also be possible to have an addition to your armor/clothing that helps, for example an extra leather strap that the cannon could use to stay securely in place.  There are many possibilities for this, especially with the artificer's many tool proficiencies.

Comment: Yeah. I slept on the matter and basically changed my mind. Answer updated.

Comment: "A Small eldritch cannon occupies its space, and a Tiny one can be held in one hand.". This says that you CAN hold it in your hand, but does not say anything about how you use it while it is in your hand. This and the fact that I can control it from 60ft away leads me to believe that my hands are not any part of it's operation. It is also interesting to note that there is no mention of occupied space for the tiny version. I wanted to be able to do this for flavor, but for me it is not worth giving up the use of my hand or gimping my movement. It sounds like I should just leave it on the ground

Comment: @kel The tiny version that *can* be held in one hand (as opposed to two) would *have* to be held in the hand if it wasn't left to just occupy a space on its own. Essentially, you're able to move the cannon up to your movement instead of its 15 foot limit for the cost of one free hand. I think the designers were very conscious about the balance of the cannon when compared to other spellcasting classes.

Comment: Saying that you "need a free hand to operate the cannon if you're carrying it" and that it is a requirement is ignoring your necessary and sufficient conditions; it is not strictly RAW. As such it is left up to the DM to decide whether it needs to be carried or not if it is on your person. You should have addressed that you believe the intention of the rule is that it must be carried, and that this is for balance sake (I believe that too, the artillerist is a powerful subclass to a powerful class), but understand that it is not concretely a rule.

Comment: No, actually I'm taking issue with the reading "A small eldritch cannon occupies its space, and a tiny one can be held in one hand." I'm pointing out (from a logician's viewpoint of necessary and sufficient conditions) that being tiny means the cannon can be held, but it doesn't state it must be held to carry it on your person. As such it isn't RAW that holding it is a requirement to carry or use while carrying. This would put the rule of whether it can be attached to your person in the jurisdiction of the DM as there isn't a RAW for it.

Comment: Instead of saying it is a rule (that you carry the cannon if you want to use it while it is on your person) you should mention that this rule isn't RAW but is likely RAI.

Comment: Important question: what's the difference between the cannon sitting on this guys shoulder, and the guy sitting on a horse?

Comment: @rev The cannon is an object and therefore isn't subject to the rules on mounted combat or AoE effects that can affect multiple creatures. This is covered in the second bullet point of the answer ;-)

Comment: "...so you'd probably have to evaluate the rules interaction in this context." Isn't that the point of the question...?

Comment: @jason The question is "can the cannon be carried on the body without the use of the hands." That's a separate question from "can the cannon be treated as a creature which would allow it to use the rules for mounting." The latter begs the question of how to deal with the cannon as a creature, which falls outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: The question is "Can [it] still ride or be carried elsewhere on the body." and therefore I disagree: it's directly relevant. If the cannon can use the mounting rules, that answers the question. If not, you wouldn't have mentioned it. Anyway, it just seemed a weird delegation back to the asker when trying to answer the question.

Comment: @jason but making the cannon a creature has *other* implications such as adding it to the initiative and the fact that it would then be a valid target for spells and abilities that can target creatures. If you say that the cannon can use mounting rules, you're addressing one issue but creating a while new set of associated issues that fall outside of the scope of the question. That's my point.